# How to get carrier name from dual sim phone Android with API level 16?

Tags: java, android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am creating an app with minimum sdk version 16.My question is how to get the carrier name of both the carriers in a dual sim phone.

I used this code but it dosenot work with sdk v16

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
```

And also I want to get the name of the carrier in string format.

Comment: There was no official SDK support for dual SIMs back in API Level 16.

Comment: There must be some way around?

Comment: You are welcome to contact the device manufacturer for your device and ask them if they have some proprietary API for accessing details of both SIM cards.

Comment: so from which api does dual sim support is there

Comment: Android's limited multi-SIM support in the SDK started in [Android 5.1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) (API Level 22).

Comment: So please tell me how to do it for android 5.1

Comment: @Neil : see my answer for android 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubscriptionManager` is available in API 22

use the following code to get carrier names for dual sim phone

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
    List<String> carrierNames = new ArrayList<>();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        for (int i = 0; i < subscriptionInfos.size(); i++) {
            carrierNames.add(subscriptionInfos.get(i).getCarrierName().toString());
        }
    }
```